# C - Writing char arrays to a file

Tags: c, file

I have the following struct:

```
struct visitordata {
    char name[25];
    char email[25];
    int id;
    char reg_time[9];
};
```

I want to write data from these visitors into a file. I'm reading this data from the CLI:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct visitordata mydata;
    char name[25], email[25], eventid[10], c;
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    strcpy(mydata.name, name);
    //etc.
}
```

Now when I try to write to the file:

```
lseek(handle, -sizeof(mydata.name), SEEK_END);
fputs(handle, &mydata.name);
```

This writes the input the user gave alright, but also some gibberish, since I allocated `char name[25]`

How can I allocate the char array sizes after reading from the command line? I'm pretty new to this, please don't be harsh. Thank you!

Comment: You only reserve 25 chars for the name. If the user input is longer then you write to memory that is not yours (buffer-overflow). In your struct you can allocate dynamical length string by using `mydata.name = new char(strlen(name)+1)`. But you should also assure, not to read more chars from `name` as you reserved chars for it in the first place. E.g. by using `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`. And maybe reserve a bit more than just 25 chars. Also assure that the string are '\0' terminated.

Comment: If you can, you should not do these tasks in C, since you have plenty chances of shooting yourself in the foot. Consider Java or Go, they protect you from buffer overflows and other memory corruption, format string attacks, heap allocation errors and some more. Once you get more experienced, you can switch to C if you really want to.

Comment: I have to do it in C...

Comment: @RolandIllig - why suggest an unrelated language? Will you tell a kernel developer to write the code in java?

Comment: @cwschmidt Okay, I can allocate `mydata.name` as `new char(strlen(name)+1)`. But in this case, how do I declare it in the struct? I can't do `char name[];` on all three strings. Also, how do I declare the `name` for `scanf("%s", name);` so that it's just as big as the user input?

Comment: @lte__ on structure, you can define `char *myname.name`. For `name` you can allocate a longer buffer, say `char name[100]`.

Comment: @alvits Okay, what I don't understand is, if I define `char *myname.name`, then `char name[100]`, then I read from the console like `scanf("%s", name);` and then do `strcpy(mydata.name, name);`, isn't `mydata.name` going to be a 100 char long array? Why?

Comment: You don't do it that way. You allocate a memory for `myname.name` to be as long as the length of `name`. `myname.name=malloc(strlen(name)+1); strcpy(myname.name,name)`.

Comment: But if you prefer to have a fixed length name, force scanf to only read as much as what is allowed for the variable.

Comment: What do you want the contents of the file to look like?

Comment: @alvits Okay, then how do I declare `name` so I can use it with `scanf("%s", name)`?

Comment: @immibis it should look like `Jason jason@here.com 2343 22:34`

Comment: I think your problem is with the line `lseek(handle, -sizeof(mydata.name), SEEK_END);`.

Comment: @immibis please do elaborate! :)

Comment: I just noticed `fputs(handle, &mydata.name);` in your post. `mydata.name` being a character array is sufficient but you used address of `&`. You should get a warning like: `warning: passing argument 2 of ‘fputs’ from incompatible pointer type`. And a note: `expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[25]’`. Not the root cause of your issue though.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct visitordata mydata;

memset(mydata, 0, sizeof mydata);

if (scanf("%24s %24s", mydata.name, mydata.email) == 2) {
    ...
}
```

The `memset` fills `mydata` with `00` bytes, so that your file doesn't contain random data.

When passing an array to a function, only a pointer to its first element is really passed, and this is exactly what `scanf` expects. Note that for reading an `int`, you would have to write:

```
if (scanf("%d", &mydata.id) == 1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In this case, you don't want to fill the entire structure with nulls.  There is an integer in there!  Also, your sizeof syntax is wrong.  You need to wrap the mydata in parentheses.

Comment: C++ is unrelated but the documentation only exist in C++. I would love to find the equivalent C documentation.

Comment: I deleted the C++ reference as well. Here's the C documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-sizeof-Operator

Comment: At the very end of that page, there is a link to the C documentation. Alternatively, you could replace the `cpp` in the URL with a `c`.

Answer (score -2):

Use `strlen(name)` to get how many character are in the name.

Comment: There's gonna be 25 since I declared it to be `char name[25]`.

Comment: Just wrong. If `name` isn't null terminated, `strlen()` won't return the correct length. It's better to force `scanf()` to only accept 25 characters including null terminator.